# Closet floor water leak

Tags: hardwood-floor

I have a mysterious water leak on closet floor. I want to open it up to see what’s underneath. What tools do I need and any precaution/proper way to do so? or just brute force pry it open? Want to reduce the repair cost.
Picture of the closet floor attached. Wet spots circled.
[image]

Comment: Water usually does not flow up unless a leak spraying water up.  Check the ceiling first

Comment: What do you store in the closet?  Perhaps the spots are from some liquid leaking from a container.

Comment: Cedar wood planks, will change color over time (getting dark)

Answer (score 1):

Wet spots on top of a floor like shown are more than likely from above the floor as opposed to under the floor. You should investigate if there is:

1. Condensation from something above dripping down.
2. Possible roof leak from above the closet ceiling
3. Plumbing leak if there is living space on the floor level above the closet.
4. Spill or leak from something simply stored in the closet.

One thing you can check is to lay down something like a split open plastic garbage bag over the damp area of the floor. Then over a few days try to see if there is additional wetness on the plastic sheeting from above. This will help to eliminate whether there may actually be a water leak below the floor of the closet.

Answer (score 0):

If the closet previously had a bucket of Damp-Rid or another product that contains calcium chloride for humidity control, and if the bucket spilled or overflowed, you could have a permanent wet spot. Boots with ice melting pellets stuck to them and left on the closet floor would have the same effect.

Calcium chloride absorbs moisture from the air to such an extent that it is deliquescent, i.e., it creates a puddle and dissolves itself.

The remedy, if this is the cause of the wet spot, is to use a wet rag to dilute the liquid, then a dry rag to absorb it. Allow to dry overnight and repeat every day until the spot disappears. It may take many dilutions to achieve the goal.